# How to remove rows in a column with certain value in Excel file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, sklearn-pandas

I have data like this:

[image: userdata]

I want to remove the rows in user ID_2 column which the data is more than and less than 5 digit

Comment: `df = df.loc[df['user ID_2'].astype(str).str.len().gt(5)]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is

> which the data is more than and less than 5 digit

Which means only 5 digits values are required, I slightly modified @ChrisA comment to fit the requirement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userID': [20394756382,29304857203,20294857642,20293847564,20192837453],
                   'UserID2' : [38493,2212324,30498,30928,432]})

df = df.loc[df['UserID2'].astype(str).str.len().eq(5)]
print(df)
        userID  UserID2
0  20394756382    38493
2  20294857642    30498
3  20293847564    30928
```

Answer (score 0):

Select required column and check if value/10000 > 0 for more than 5 digit. Then replace that value with null or anything. Basically you are filtering data.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filtering-data-with-pandas-query-method/